# how to automatically update current date to 1 week in php to the server

Tags: php, mysql

I already have SQL table with date column mentioned below.

```
SL.no   Date       name
1     15-02-2017   krish
```

I want to automatically update column date to one week when the current date is equal to table column date.

**Example**

---

Today date is 15-02-2017

My SQL column date is 15-02-2017

---

Then i want to update this automatically to 1 week when i access my home page.

Is this possible to do?

I hope you understand my questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: what is your column's data type? it seems that this `15-02-2017` is not the correct format the DB expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your example data your date field is a VARCHAR or CHAR type. 
You need to use STR_TO_DATE to make it possible to use + INTERVAL 1 WEEK and DATE_FORMAT to convert back to your CHAR or VARCHAR field.

```
UPDATE
 [table]
SET Date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('15-02-2017', '%d-%m-%Y') + INTERVAL 1 WEEK, '%d-%m-%Y')
WHERE
 Date = '15-02-2017'
```

Comment: Thank you Raymond for your response. Now only i see this post.

Comment: My table date fields is VARCHAR i want to update like 2017-02-15 or 15-02-2017